# How do I use behat to verify all state listed in the option drop down

Tags: behat

```
<select data-drupal-selector="edit-state" id="edit-state">
 <options value ="Alabama">Alabama</option>
 <options value ="Alabama">Alaska</option>
 .......
 ......
```

CSS for selector dorpdown

Answer (score 0):

Asking a question should be more specific, like i tried this and gave me this error, so you should show what have you tried.

Use `findAll` to find all the option from this specific select in a variable then do a loop and check the attributes for what you need.